# Openlayers 3 point, polygons, linestring are rendered but not visible

Tags: openlayers-3, chromium, chromium-os

On Chromium OS, Chromium browser i open my ol3 app and i cant see point, polygons, linestring features. 
They appear and disappear , blank page is getting displayed.

How do i solve the paint issue ?

Comment: Post your code in plunker so we can see whats happening?

Comment: Actually its the same code, which i am running on Chrome in Windows 10 and there it works perfectly fine. Its only when i run the same code in Chromium OS Chromium browser that i am facing the issue. I think it is the paint issue. I can even see the tooltips which i had added on hover over Points, Polygons, Linestrings. But the actual shapes are not visible.